# Erro 404 ao criar routes no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

boas, não consigo criar uma route para um determinado controller sendo que ocorre sempre um erro 404 ao carregar a página.
No caso de eu definir esse controller como default_controller a página é apresentada normalmente.

Alguem sabe do que possa ser? Não alterei nada no ficheiro .htaccess

**Config**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/CodeIgniter/core/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Utilizador extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index(){
        //print_r($this->Utilizador_model->teste());
        echo "pppp";
    }

    }


?>
```

**Routes:**

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
    $route['404_override'] = '';
    $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
    $route['utilizador'] = 'utilizador';
```

**Ficheiro onde estou a chamar o controller:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="bslf form">
        <form action="<?= base_url('utilizador') ?>" method="post">
          <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>       
          <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Log in</button>
          </div>       
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```